# Differential equation$ (x^2-x)y' = (y^2+y)$

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

Can i get help solving the differential equation
$$y' = \frac{y^2+y }{x^2 -x}$$

I tried searching but could not find anything similar.

Thank you!

Comment: ...and use partial fraction decomposition

Comment: You can solve this by separating the variables, i.e. write $y'=\frac{dy}{dx}$, bringt all the x-terms to one side, all the y-terms to the other and integrate on both sides, i.e
$$ \int \frac{dy}{y^2+y} = \int \frac{dx}{x^2-x}$$
Now solve this.

Comment: Right! Thank you very much!

Answer (score 1):

Separate the variables to get

$$\ \frac{dy}{y^2+y}=\frac{dx}{x^2-x}$$

And now you can easily integrate both sides

Comment: Right! Thank you very much!